# F# like mailboxprocessor but with multiple consumers

Tags: c#, f#, actor, mailboxprocessor

I am looking for a producer/consumer communication mechanism in either F# or C# that allows for concurrent processing of incoming messages by multiple consumers and generation of replies to multiple producers.
System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection is not bad but is not message oriented like the F# mailboxprocessor. A message based abstraction (request/reply based) is highly desirable.
Unlike the F# mailboxprocessor mutable state inside it is not required.
If a read from the mailbox (message queue) would block then the thread should be released to the thread pool as in F#. A throttle (flow control to slow down producers) would be ideal but not required.
Any ideas?

Comment: I expect high level ideas how to turn the multiple producer, single consumer F# mailboxprocessor into a multiple producer, multiple consumer kind of mailboxprocessor. Sample code, references to web sites, any other ideas.

Comment: Have you looked at [Akka.NET](http://getakka.net/docs/)? Both a C# and an F# API, and lots of ways to [send messages to multiple consumers](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Routers): round-robin, broadcast, and so on. Akka might be the library you're looking for.

Comment: Akka.NET Seems like a good option, thanks. I can't determine yet if threads that would block get released to the thread pool.